# Can we implement ERC2535 on already deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I have a simple question.

I have a transparent upgradeable proxy already deployed on the mainnet and I have also upgraded the implementation a few times.
So, is it possible to somehow implement the Diamond Storage approach on this already deployed upgradeable contract?
As we know we can't change a single bit from the Proxy contract, so I think it is not possible.

Am I missing something?